# More than one export was found that matches the constraint for non ICollection<T>

Tags: c#, mef

I looked at several other other posts that talk about using:

```
[ImportMany]
IEnumerable<IPlugin> plugins;
```

but in my case it is not a collection.

Please see below for my code and error message:

```
[Export(typeof(ITransactionActionMasterDao))]
public class TransactionActionMasterDao : BaseDao, ITransactionActionMasterDao

public abstract class BaseTransactionGenerator : ITransactionGenerator
{
 [Import(typeof(ITransactionActionMasterDao))]
 private ITransactionActionMasterDao transactionActionMasterDao;

 public BaseTransactionGenerator()
    {
        //Grab all the assemblies in the current folder
            AggregateCatalog catalog = new AggregateCatalog(new AssemblyCatalog(  typeof(TransactionActionMasterDao).Assembly) );

        CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
        // This will set the fields (aka execute the [Import])

         **//below line getting error**
        container.ComposeParts(this);
    }
}

 public class ManualTransactionGenerator : BaseTransactionGenerator
 {       
    public ManualTransactionGenerator():base()
    {        
    }
 }
```

ManualTransactionGenerator and BaseTransactionGenerator are both in one same C# class library project.

TransactionGeneratorsIntegrationTest is present in another UnitTest project

```
 public class TransactionGeneratorsIntegrationTest
 {
   [TestMethod]        
    public void IT_GenerateManualTransactions()
    {
      ManualTransactionGenerator generator = new ManualTransactionGenerator()
    }
 }
```

Error Message: 
The composition produced a single composition error. The root cause is provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for more detailed information.

1) More than one export was found that matches the constraint: 
    ContractName    HL.DataAccess.Adjustment.Contracts.DataAccessObjects.ITransactionActionMasterDao
    RequiredTypeIdentity    HL.DataAccess.Adjustment.Contracts.DataAccessObjects.ITransactionActionMasterDao

**UPDATE:**

We changed our design and new code looks like this

```
[Export(typeof(ITransactionActionMasterDao))]

public class TransactionActionMasterDao : BaseDao, ITransactionActionMasterDao

[Export(typeof(ITransactionActionMasterDao))]

public class CustomerTransactionActionMasterDao : BaseDao, ITransactionActionMasterDao

public abstract class BaseTransactionGenerator : ITransactionGenerator
{
 [Import(typeof(ITransactionActionMasterDao))]
 private ITransactionActionMasterDao transactionActionMasterDao;

 public BaseTransactionGenerator()
    {
        **//Below lines will throw error**
            AggregateCatalog catalog = new AggregateCatalog(new AssemblyCatalog(  typeof(TransactionActionMasterDao).Assembly),
new AssemblyCatalog(  typeof(CustomerTransactionActionMasterDao ).Assembly) );

**//This is correct. We need to add ONLY one. Not both**
AggregateCatalog catalog = new AggregateCatalog(new AssemblyCatalog(  typeof(TransactionActionMasterDao).Assembly);

        CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
        // This will set the fields (aka execute the [Import])

         **//below line getting error**
        container.ComposeParts(this);
    }
}
```

This solved our issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may be encountering a problem with side-by-side loading of multiple versions of the assembly containing the `[Export]` attribute. To test this theory, try the following:

1. Change the `[Import]` to an `[ImportMany]`.
2. If (when) you observe more than one item in the list, examine each instance to determine the location of the assembly it was loaded from.

   ```
   transactionActionMasterDao[i].GetType().Assembly.Location
   ```

If this is the case, you may need to use assembly binding redirection to ensure only one copy of the assembly containing the export is loaded.

Comment: @Ziggler two instances of the same class from the same location?

Comment: I did what you said. I am getting count as 1 and location as XX\\[MyTestProject]\bin\Debug\\[Assembly name of TransactionActionMasterDao]

Comment: Sam : I updated my question. We changed our design and it solved our issue. We need to make sure we add only one class per namespace. If we try to add class A and Class B belonging to namespace N it is throwing exception. We added either A or either B to AggegrateCatalog